# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: dictionary, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a problem with map. I want to add map to my application so user can look for Mosques that are near to there location.

I already have a Model Mosque that content "name , location , information , Image" .

I have tried  function to display map:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>

@section Scripts {
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY"></script>
    <script>
        function initMap() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                        center: { lat: 37.12, lng: 102 },
                        zoom: 15,
                    });}


    </script>
}

@sec
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no question is being asked.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a problem with map. I want to add map to my application so user
> can look for Mosques that are near to there location.

It seems, you are using [google map API](https://mapsplatform.google.com/pricing/) in your scenario. As [google map doesn't have dev test free account](https://mapsplatform.google.com/pricing/). Thus, I cannot test according to your scenario.

Therefore, I am testing your scenario using [Bing API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/locations/) which provides [dev testing free API key](https://www.bingmapsportal.com/Application#). According to your requirement, first of all , you need to obtain latitude and longitude coordinates of the location (for instance Mosques)

After getting [latitude and longitude](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/locations/location-data#top-level-locations-resource-fields) you have to set pin or point marker to visualize your location.

Finally bind the location within your map canvas.

Let's have a look in action.

**Get Bing Dev Test Key:**

Its quite easy to get your dev [test api key for bing map](https://www.bingmapsportal.com/Application#). You can [visit here](https://www.bingmapsportal.com/Application#) and register in order to get API key. Its completely free.

[image]

**Map Canvas:**

```cs
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type location..." id="locationName">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="SearchMultipleLocation()" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<hr />
<div id='mapCanvas' style='width: 75vw; height: 75vh;'></div>
```

**Map Script:**

```cs
@section scripts {
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?branch=release&callback=loadMapScenario' async defer></script>
    <script>

        function SearchMultipleLocation() {
            alert("Click")
            GetMapPushPinLocation();
        }
        var map, infobox;

        function GetMapPushPinLocation() {
            map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#mapCanvas', {
                credentials: "AmPhY-Ia2t-NH3_pzWXzcFcU3ezL4mAAYW2basjlmszq3Ml_tWQb_pT-7-TBtrNW",
                center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(31.628674, -7.992047), // Put your country Lat and Log here
                zoom: 8
            });

            //Create an infobox at the center of the map but don't show it.
            infobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(map.getCenter(), {
                visible: false
            });

            //Assign the infobox to a map instance.
            infobox.setMap(map);

            //Create random locations in the map bounds.
            var randomLocations = Microsoft.Maps.TestDataGenerator.getLocations(10, map.getBounds());

            for (var i = 0; i < randomLocations.length; i++) {
                var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(randomLocations[i]);

                //Store some metadata with the pushpin.
                pin.metadata = {
                    title: 'Pin ' + i,
                    description: 'Description for pin' + i
                };

                //Add a click event handler to the pushpin.
                Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'click', pushpinClicked);

                //Add pushpin to the map.
                map.entities.push(pin);
            }
        }

        function pushpinClicked(e) {
            //Make sure the infobox has metadata to display.
            if (e.target.metadata) {
                //Set the infobox options with the metadata of the pushpin.
                infobox.setOptions({
                    location: e.target.getLocation(),
                    title: e.target.metadata.title,
                    description: e.target.metadata.description,
                    visible: true
                });
            }
           }

        }
    </script>
}
```

**Note:** Point to remember that, in `TestDataGenerator.getLocations` I am having random location, here you would need to know exact latitude and longitude coordinates of your desired location.

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on [bing map multiple location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/map-control-concepts/infoboxes/multiple-pushpins-and-infoboxes) you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/map-control-concepts/infoboxes/multiple-pushpins-and-infoboxes)

Comment: thank you this was very useful 
https://stackoverflow.com/users/9663070/md-farid-uddin-kiron

Comment: Hello,  have you tried the solution? Did you able to resolve the issue? Is there anything else that I can help you on this?

Comment: Hello Sir Md Farid Uddin Kiron. I have tried to use  Bing API instead of google map API and it works very well.
thank for you helpful solution.

Comment: Hello, Is there anything else that I can help you on this?

Comment: I have a model called Mosque contains : Name location longitude latitude .
I want to display my mosques in map I know  that this is possible.

Comment: Well, in `randomLocations[i]` you have to get your desired location thn pin it.